# How to get an array containing the values of an attribute for an Ember model?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

For example if I have a Person model with the "name" attribute, what can I call in Ember.js with Ember Data that returns an array of all the names in the Person model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
App.Person.find().then( function(data) {
  var namesArray = data.getEach('name');
});
```

*UPDATE RE: COMMENT (what if i want to do this from setupController...)*

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
  App.Person.find().then( function(data) {
    controller.set('variablename', data.getEach('name') };
  });
}
```

Comment: What if I want to set up something in `setupController` like `setupController: function(controller){controller.set('variablename', App.Person.find().???? }`

Answer (score 2):

```
App.PersonsRoute = Ember.Route.find({
  setupController: function() {
    // Get all persons
    this.controllerFor('persons').set('content', App.Person.find());
  } 
});


App.PersonsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  allNames: function() {
    var persons = this.get('content') || [];
    return persons.getEach('name');
  }.property('content.[]')
});
```

In short, when you have a collection (an array of objects) and you want to build a new array of the values of a certain property, use [getEach](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_getEach). `getEach('foo')` is an alias for `mapProperty('foo')`.